# svelte lifecycle functions from caller?

Tags: svelte

```
  new App({
    target:  document.getElementById('some id')
  });
```

We start our app like this in the opening file. On their guides https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte  there is a lifecycle hook for when the component has loaded, but can this be used from the one who calls it?

EG

```
  new App({
    target:  document.getElementById('some id'),
    onMount: () => {
      // do something
    }
  });
```

Currently we use the onMount hook in the base component then emit an event to the window object.. but it feels very wrong :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `App` component can export a mount function as a prop...

```svelte
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    export let mount = () => {};
    
    onMount(() => {
        mount();
    });
</script>
```

... and then you can set that prop when [initializing the app](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api):

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        mount: () => { console.log('mounted!'); }
    }
});
```

Comment: ahh smart! Bit of a new way to look at things in svelte compared to vue. Thanks